# Blackberry Keyboard Lock timeout

Tags: blackberry, locking

I want this blackberry 9700 to "fully lock" as soon as I click the icon for the "Keyboard Lock" application.  Currently I have to wait 5 to 7 seconds for the screen to go dark after each time I click the "Keyboard Lock" icon.  During that time if something touches the touch pad, then the 5-7 second timer resets and you have to wait another 5 to 7 seconds for the screen to go dark and "fully lock"

After it finally goes dark, touching the touch pad does not reset the timer.  At that point it is "fully locked" and requires a key to be pressed.

How can I get it to "fully lock" as soon as the lock icon is clicked?   I want the screen to go dark immediately, and for it to require a key press to request an unlock.

I have tried Options -> Screen/Keyboard -> Backlight Timeout ... etc ... none of that reduces the timeout for the "Keyboard Lock" application.  And there does not seem to be an option screen for the "Keyboard Lock" application, that I can find.

NOTE: This is occurring with BlackBerry 9700 v5.0.0.330 (Platform 5.1.0.91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having the same problem some time ago with my BB 9500 and the 9520 later. For both devices, a firmware upgrade to the latest version of OS 5.0 fixed the problem. It seems like they made several changes with the locking mechanism in the most recent OS updates and I don't think you can change the behavior in the options without the upgrade.

Comment: I'm using v5.0.0.330 is that late enough?  Apparently not :-/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know in which version it was fixed. I'm currently running OS 5.0.0.580 on BB 9520 and it works.